# Inverse transformation for exponential function

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function

Given the function:

$$ f(x)\ :=\ 2^{\frac{x+1}{x-1}} $$

What is the correct approach for $f(x)$ transformation as its inverse?

Kindly regards for the support.

Comment: You can just write a ^ - for example 2^n $2^n$. Remember to bracket the power with {} for it to format properly.

Comment: I tried to make it more simple by using the logarithmic rules with base 2 , but didnt succeed(got to the same place). Logically it must be like a mirror for the earliest - so i tried mapping the function as a mirror too but yet, didnt succeed,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inverse function:

$$ g(y)\ :=\ \frac{\log_2(y)+1}{\log_2(y)-1} $$

**REMARK**   Domains:

$$ f : \mathbb R\setminus\{1\}\ \rightarrow\ (0;\infty)\setminus\{2\} $$
and
$$ g : (0;\infty)\setminus{2}\ \rightarrow\ \mathbb R\setminus\{1\} $$

> 

**Explanation:**

Function $\ f\ $ is a composition of two functions:

$$ f = \psi\circ \phi $$

where $\ \phi(s)\ :=\ \frac{s+1}{s-1}\ $ and $\ \psi(t)\ :=\ 2^t.\ $ The inverse of $\ \phi\ $ is this function itself. The inverse of the exponential function $\ \psi\ $ is $\ \log_2.\ $ Thus inverse of $\ f\ $ is $\ g\ :=\ \phi\circ\log_2.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what did you do? If you can note some short points for your solution flow - would help a lot.

Comment: @WlodAA Your answer is not clear enough - many functions and their inverses have the domain of $(0; \infty)$.

Comment: @Mabadai, the judgements about the required detail of the solutions is highly inconsistent around here at StackExchange. Often some very fractional hints instead of answers are accepted and praised.

Comment: @TobyMak, it's not clear what you are trying to say. Of course, "many,,," -- so what? The **QUESTION** has not provided the domains for the given function $\ f.\ $ I was nice, and I have done it, as well as I have provided the domains also for the inverse, of course.

Comment: @Wlod AA maybe you are right, but, i asked the question her (in StackExchange) because of the explanation, else, i could just use a wolfram alpha or any other calculator with inverse functions engine...

Comment: @Mabadai, how could I know that you'd use wolfram (I've never done it in my life). I wish, you'd tell us in advance.

Comment: @WlodAA The question is 'how do I find the inverse function', not 'what is the answer'. Also, my point was you did not have to include the domain and range, and adding this information might distract the OP from the most important point - how you get to the answer.

Comment: Anyway, if the OP thinks the answer is useful, let him/her decide.

Comment: It's been a loooong-loooooong time since I used phrase "how do I find" in the elementary/high school way. I don't think I will relearn it now. It's hard to teach an old dog an OLD trick.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is :
$$
x = {{\log(y) + \log(2)} \over {\log(y)-\log(2)}}
$$
Demo : 
$$
y = f(x) \\
{{x+1} \over {x-1}} = {{\log y} \over {\log 2}} = P \\
x+1=P(x-1) \\
x+1=Px-P \\
x={{P+1} \over {P-1}} = {{{{\log y} \over {\log 2}}+1} \over  {{\log y} \over {\log 2}}-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Got one more question: In "Demo" , 2nd line, its your declaration, right? If so, why did you equalize (x+1)/(x-1) to (logy)/log2?

Comment: @Daniel Pol, you have provided only one half of a demonstration.

Comment: exponent can be calculated using a logarythm in base 2. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: Your usage of natural logarithm can be viewed as elegant.

Comment: If you provided answer before mine (perhaps you did), I didn't see it at the time. If I did see, I would not give mine which was but a trivial variation ($\log$ vs. $\log_2$).

Comment: @Daniel Pol, you've demonstrated only a retraction, not an isomorphism. (If you said that the steps go up too, not only down, then indeed, it'd be an isomorphism).

Comment: It is not ask me about domains, isomophism or retraction (i dont do any retraction), only ask me about a inverse function, and not give me domains. If he would ask me about domain's he would write me him self in a comment, that he need that. Wish you all best.